# How to redirect standard input and output with Bash

Tags: bash, io

```
#!/bin/bash
./program < input.txt > output.txt
```

The `> output.txt` part is being ignored so output.txt ends up being empty.

This works for the `sort` command so I expected to also work for other programs.

Any reason this doesn't work? How should I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps the output from ./program is going to the standard error? Try `2> output.txt`

Comment: @Richante LOL that's odd but now works (why do you write the answer in a comment?) thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the output you're seeing is from `stderr`, not `stdout`.  To redirect both of them to a file, do this:

```
./program < input.txt > output.txt 2>&1
```

or

```
./program < input.txt &> output.txt
```

Comment: How would you do something like `./program < input.txt | program2 | program n > output.txt` ?