# Taking input from file without using file handling

Tags: bash, python-3.x, terminal

I want to take input from a file(`input.txt`) into my `.py` file and display it in an output file(output.txt). I don't want to use file handling at all.

I tried following in terminal:

```
$ python3 hello.py > output.txt
```

and a file was created with the output.

But is there a method such that I can take input from a file to the `.py` file and it generates `output.txt`.

something like:

```
$ input.txt > python3 hello.py > output.txt
```

Comment: You were close : `python3 hello.py < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: Thanks @Aaron it worked..!! :)

Comment: You're welcome ! I suggest you delete the question, because I'm certain there are a lot of duplicates (which is why I didn't post the solution in an answer)

Comment: @Aaron duplicates shouldn't be deleted, they should be linked to a dupe, dupes aren't bad they're different ways of expressing the problem that others might find

Comment: @EricRenouf I agree the question isn't bad itself, and it would have been best if someone (like me) had taken the time to link to a duplicate. However with such a basic question I'm not sure there's much value to the community in spending the time to find a duplicate (and obviously none to the asker since he has his answer now). Still, you're right and I'll try to find a duplicate if I have the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect standard input and output with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076741/how-to-redirect-standard-input-and-output-with-bash)